# Iterate through HTML inputs and set values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to iterate through some input elements and replace their values if empty.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var input = $('.test').val();
    var isValid;
    $("input").each(function (){
     var element = $(this);
      if (element.val() == "") {
        $('.test').val('empty');
      } 
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test" type="text">
<input class="test" type="text">
<input class="test" type="text">
<input class="test" type="text">
<input class="test" type="text" value="test">
```

I want to change if a value is empty to "empty", but if it's not, to keep its own value. However it is setting every input to "empty" despite the last one having its own value. Can someone help me?

Comment: Use `element.val('empty')` instead of `$('.test').val('empty')`. You are already using `element.val() == ""` in the `if` condition ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
element.val('empty');
```

Instead of

```
$('.test').val('empty');
```

Because `$('.test').val('empty');` is setting value `empty` for all element that uses class `test`. As you want to change the value of a specific element, use that `element` reference instead of `$('.test')`.

Here is your code with that *little* modification.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var input = $('.test').val();
    var isValid;
    $("input").each(function (){
     var element = $(this);
      if (element.val() == "") {
        element.val('empty');
      } 
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test" type="text">
<input class="test" type="text">
<input class="test" type="text">
<input class="test" type="text">
<input class="test" type="text" value="test">
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I see my mistake now! I am selecting your answer as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can check the attribute value and it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var input = $('.test').val();
    var isValid;
    $("input").each(function (){
        var element = $(this);
      if (element.attr('value') == "") {
        $('.test').val('empty');
      } 
    });
```

Comment: What is wrong with `element.val() == ""`? It is already working for OP